# OAuth 2.0 Playground - Examples of Headers for sending email with Gmail API v1

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have been searching all day for the format I need to use to add Headers to the OAuth 2.0 Playground to be able to send an email within the OAuth 2.0 Playground.

I have tried From, Subject, Sender, To but I still get the following error.

{
"error": {
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"message": "Recipient address required",
"code": 400,
"errors": [
{
"reason": "invalidArgument",
"message": "Recipient address required",
"domain": "global"
}
]
}
}

I would love to see an example of what you have done to get this to work.

Thx
Marty